# Chrome Ajax call error: ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm using the following AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
url: ajaxUrl,
data:{
    'action':'gallery_inject',
    'gallery_id': galleryId,
    'banner_id': bannerId,
    'use_thumb': use_thumb,
    'lazy_load': lazy_load,
    'use_carousel': use_carousel
},
dataType: 'JSON',
```

But getting the following error in Chrome:

```
GET https://example.com/ajax.php?action=gallery_inject&gallery_id=29&banner_id=54&use_thumb=1&lazy_load=1&use_carousel=0 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

What is this vague error? I've checked the URL and it's fine, and the value for those parameters are valid. And it works fine in Firefox.

Comment: Using AdBlock or similar extensions in Chrome? Whitelist the domain or disable the culprit.

Comment: It was AdBlock, thanks. The specific field it blocks is "banner_id". If you want to post an answer go ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you by any chance using AdBlock or similar extensions in Chrome?
Whitelist the domain or disable the culprit.